# Multicolumn aligns text always right

Tags: tables, multicolumn, kile

I'm in the Latex tabular environment. I want to align the text in a multicolumn to the left, but it does not work. It is always alignt to the right.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}\hline
\textbf{number of lanes:} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}\textbf{8 (20 m width)} & \multicolumn{2}{l|} \textbf{10 (25 m width)}\\
  & distance & free space loss & distance & free space loss \\\hline 
\textbf{lane length 25 m} & 16.008 m & 10 dB & 17.678 m & 30 dB\\\hline
\textbf{lane length 50 m} & 26.926 m & 20 dB & 27.951 m & 40 dB\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

and the output is always:

[image: table output]

Waht I'm doing wrong?

I'm on Kubuntu 20.10 with Kile kile 2.9.93

OS: Kubuntu 20.10
KDE-Plasma-Version: 5.19.5
KDE-Frameworks-Version: 5.74.0
Qt-Version: 5.14.2
Kernel-Version: 5.8.0-63-generic
Architecture: 64-bit
Prozessors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz
RAM: 7,6 GiB
GPU: Mesa DRI Intel® HD Graphics 4000

(If you ask, it's for a vital parameters telemetry radio system for swimmers)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Did you try using `\multicolumn{cols}{pos}{text}` correctly? It looks like your _text_ ist not in bracktes.

Comment: Thanks, this will work

Answer (score 2):

You may give a chance to `tabularray` and `siunitx` (loaded as `tabularray` library) packages. Using them you will get simple control on cells contents aligning and writing units. For details of all possibilities of those two powerful packages are thoroughly described in theirs documentation.

- a case, when all cells contents is left aligned:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \sisetup{text-series-to-math}
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,3-Z}, vlines,
             colspec = {*{5}{X[l,m]}}, 
             column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
number of lanes:
    &   \SetCell[c=2]{l} 8 (\qty{20}{m} width)
        &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{l} 10 (\qty{25}{m} width)    
                &                       \\
    &   distance 
        &   free space loss 
            &   distance 
                &   free space loss     \\
lane length \qty[unit-font-command=\mathbf]{25}{m} 
    & \qty{16.008}{m} 
        &   \qty{10}{dB} 
            &   \qty{17.678}{m} 
                &   \qty{30}{dB}        \\
lane length \qty[unit-font-command=\mathbf]{50}{m} 
    &   \qty{26.926}{m} 
        &   \qty{20}{dB} 
            &   \qty{27.951}{m} 
                &   \qty{40}{dB}        \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- a case, where except first one a cells contents are centered. In this case the table specification in above MWE is changed to:

```
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,3-Z}, vlines,
             colspec = {X[l,m]*{4}{X[c,m]}},    % <---
             column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
```

and multi column cells specification to:

```
\SetCell[c=2]{c}
```

which gives:

[image]

**Edit:**

- one more possible table layout:

[image]

which you can get with the following table preamble:

```
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[l,m]*{4}{X[c,m]}},    
             column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot braces `{}` around the text of the `\multicolumn`. I also added `\raggedright` to get a nicer layout. I did this by defining a new column type `q`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|q{2cm}|q{2cm}|q{2cm}|q{2cm}|q{2cm}|}\hline
\textbf{number of lanes:} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{8 (20 m width)}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|} {\textbf{10 (25 m width)}}\\
  & distance & free space loss & distance & free space loss \\\hline 
\textbf{lane length 25 m} & 16.008 m & 10 dB & 17.678 m & 30 dB\\\hline
\textbf{lane length 50 m} & 26.926 m & 20 dB & 27.951 m & 40 dB\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is it.